# jit-lock-function enters infinite loop in inferior Python

Tags: python, emacs

Since the last update whenever I try to <kbd>M-x</kbd>`run-python` the Python shell doesn't start properly. I need to kill the process which is starting it, otherwise Emacs is locked. If then I try to type into the shell, the typing works, but as only I need to evaluate, the results will not show up, unless I interrupt the process with <kbd>C-g</kbd>. The message buffer shows this:

```
Error during redisplay: (jit-lock-function 468) signaled (quit)
```

Is this a known problem? Where should I look for the source of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a bug-report is most helpful

M-x report-emacs-bug

Comment: Thanks back. Don't make info needed by developers stack here :)